# How to format data to be in type const uint16_t for use in an spi library

Tags: c++, type-conversion, constants, spi, raspberry-pi-pico

so I have been writing some code and finished it, all I had left to do was send it over SPI. However, I didn't realise that the SPI library I am using only accepts const uint_16t data. I tried setting up a temp variable of the correct data type and using a reference to send over SPI, which works, but because it is a const variable it cant change, which is something I need it to be able to do.

Below is my code, any help with this would be great, for reference this is done in C++ and uses SPI library is part of the Raspberry Pi Pico SDK (the code is cut down as is long so only needed parts included). I did try to use pointers to change the const variable which I think you can do in C but I couldn't get it to work in C++.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated as I am very stuck as with how to go about fixing this.

Thanks,
Dean

```
class Frequency_Values{
Public:

static uint16_t position;

//constructors and special member functions here

private:
    uint16_t MSB_LUT[401];
    uint16_t LSB_LUT[401];

};
//----------static variable definition---------------------
unsigned short Frequency_Values::position = 0;
//---------------------------------------------------------

//-------------------get function definitions--------------
uint16_t Frequency_Values::get_MSB_LUT_Value()
{
    return (Frequency_Values::MSB_LUT[position]);
}

uint16_t Frequency_Values::get_LSB_LUT_Value()
{
    return (Frequency_Values::LSB_LUT[position]);
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------

Frequency_Values MSB, LSB;




int main(){

while(1){  // to show code runs multiple times
    //--------------------------------------------------
    const uint16_t LSB_Holder = LSB.get_LSB_LUT_Value();   // this is what I tried to get it in the correct data type
                                                           //which worked but as const the value wont change
    const uint16_t MSB_Holder = MSB.get_MSB_LUT_Value();    
    //--------------------------------------------------
}

    spi_write16_blocking(SPI_PORT, &LSB_Holder, 1);     
    spi_write16_blocking(SPI_PORT, &MSB_Holder, 1);     
}
```

Comment: Is `spi_write16_blocking` supposed to modify `LSB_Holder` and `MSB_Holder`?  If it is, then why are you declaring them `const`? I can't help you more than that unless you tell what errors you are seeing.

Comment: Hi @HAL9000 so spi_write16_blocking is just suppose to send the data you give it, but that data has to be of type const uint16_t. There is no errors when compiling its just that it doesnt do what I need it to. If I were to supply the spi_write_16_blocking function with data that isnt of type const uint16_t it just says that its supplied with the wrong data type

Comment: You can always use pointers to non-`const` data where pointers to `const` data is expected.  Only the other way around is problematic. If the program is not behaving the way you want, at least post observed and expected behavior. Writing to `const` variables is invalid in both C and C++, even if C might pretend the error is not there and produces some potentially bad code.

Answer (score 0):

This was eventually fixed by just removing the const specifier inside of the pico sdk, spi library.